# MATLAB 2015b: "sphere" not recognized in strel command

Tags: matlab, 3d, binary

I have a 3d binary image which I am trying to do a 3d dilation on in MATLAB 2015b. I tried:

```
se=strel('sphere',20);
3Ddilated=imdilate(3Dimage,se);
```

but I'm getting:

```
Error using strel>ParseInputs (line 1223)
Expected input number 1, STREL_TYPE, to match one of these strings:

'arbitrary', 'square', 'diamond', 'rectangle', 'octagon', 'line', 'pair', 'periodicline', 'disk', 'ball'

The input, 'sphere', did not match any of the valid strings.

Error in strel (line 147)
                [type,params] = ParseInputs(varargin{:});
```

Does strel not do 'sphere' in 2015b? Is there a good alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate a 3D spherical structuring element by yourself that is equal to what the `'sphere'` option of [`strel`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/strel.html) would give. Testing in MATLAB R2016b:

```
radius = 5;

sphereSE = strel('sphere', radius);  % Spherical element

[x, y, z] = ndgrid(-radius:radius);
arbitSE = strel(sqrt(x.^2+y.^2+z.^2) <= radius);  % The `arbitrary` argument is optional

isequal(sphereSE.Neighborhood, arbitSE.Neighborhood)  % Check equality

ans =

  logical

   1  % They give the same result
```

Comment: thanks, I'm trying this out, dilation is taking a while..dumb geometry question: should I expect different results doing 3d dilation with a radius=10 sphere than iterating through 2d by 2d image in the 3d set and doing 2d circle dilation with radius=10 (goes way faster)?

Comment: @user3470496: Dilating each 2D image in the stack with a 2D disk element is not the same as a 3D dilation with a sphere. It is faster, but not the same operation.

Answer (score 0):

You can create one yourself:

```
r = 20;
x = -r:r;
x = x.^2;
[x,y,z]=ndgrid(x,x,x);
se = (x+y+z) <= r.^2;
```